# Qunit testing an ember controller, located in a file that contains multiple controllers?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, ember.js, qunit, ember-qunit

So, I've been trying to qunit test an Ember controller, The problem is, The controller is inside a coffeeScript file, that contains multiple controllers.

Now, The [ember testing guide says](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/unit-test-helpers/#toc_available-helpers), In order to test a controller, I should use the 'moduleFor' helper like so:

`moduleFor(fullName [, description [, callbacks]])`

In my case, the full name is say: "CustomersIndexController" , But because it's included in "customers_controller.coffee" that in it self includes multiple controller, Testing it became problematic .

After an Endless digging online, I [found out](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/guides/naming-conventions.html) (Please correct me if I'm wrong) that the resolver cares only about the file name, not about the name that 'export default myModel' provides

To make it more clear, Here is my "customers_controller.coffee" :

```
`export { CustomersIndexController, CustomersItemController }`

CustomersIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
#Code goes here ......

CustomerItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
#Code goes here .....
```

And here is the `customers-controller-test.coffee` file :

```
`import { test, moduleFor } from 'ember-qunit';`
 moduleFor("controller:customers-index-controller", 'C Controller') 

 test "it's an App.Controller", -> ok(@subject())
```

I've tried all the ideas that my brain could produce...without any luck(changing the controller name from camelCase to dasherized, to absolute path, even tried importing customers_controller.coffee), But I keep getting:

```
Setup failed on it's a App.Controller: Attempting to register an unknown factory: `controller:customers-index-controller`
```

Any Help/Advice/Links are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to defined it in lower camelCase.

```
moduleFor('controller:postsIndex', 'Posts Index Controller');
```

http://jsbin.com/ruhalota/1/edit

Comment: Thank you for your reply, But that did not work for me, Already tried it. 
problem is `app/controllers/customers_controller.coffee` contains 2 controllers defined within it: CustomersIndexController & CustomerItemController , I am unable to test them, my `app/tests/controllers/customers-controller-tests` errors when i try to test moduleFor("controller:customerItemController", App.CustomerItemController')

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the documentation for the resolver with ember-cli, you'll see that it does indeed only care about the names of the files, and what is the default export of them: http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-modules

In your case, you'll need to split your controllers into multiple files, so the resolver can find and instantiate them properly. So, the two files would be:

- app/controllers/customers/index.coffee
- app/controllers/customers/item.coffee

This is all assuming you are using ember-cli. If you are still using ember-app-kit, you might need to adjust this slightly, but the same basic idea should apply.